# What is the difference between "cipher" and "encryption"?

Tags: encryption, terminology, ciphers

It seems as if they are either synonyms, or cipher was an older term for when they directly translated the same number (or almost same number) of "encrypted" characters into the same number of plaintext ones, whereas encryption means that they use such a complicated "algorithm" as to make it impossible to deduce the length of the message from just seeing the "encrypted blob", which uses highly complex "back-and-forths" to produce the final decrypted string.

Comment: You have put too many things together in one question. "Password" and "private key"
 are not related in any way. I'm removing the last line to help focus the question

Comment: Have you looked these terms for official definitions? Wiki seems to answer you directly in the first paragraph https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipher

Comment: The short answer is there's no real difference.  The Wikipedia article does a pretty good job of defining cipher  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipher  In fact, we use "block cipher" to define a type of encryption algorithm, so the terms are used interchangeably.

Comment: This reminds me of [a related question on crypto.SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/24356/inconsistent-terminology-for-ciphers-and-algorithms) that I answered a while ago.

Answer (score 6):

"Cipher" is the algorithm or process used to encrypt the data (i.e. AES, RSA, etc.). "Encryption" is the process of converting data using the aforementioned cipher.